# The right way to store floats ready for __m128

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is there any difference in speed between

```
struct V{
    float v[3];
    float get_x() { return v[0];}
    // ... some more methods
};
```

and

```
struct V{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float get_x() { return x;}
    // ... some more methods
};
```

In general my code uses the coordinates at random-access bases. In some places however I would like to use SSE instructions. I imagine the float[] storage will speed up loading and unloading the data to/from __m128. Am I right in that point?

Comment: you'll want to get them alligned

Comment: Are those two examples really of the same thing? One has four floats and the other has three.

Comment: Of course, thanks. So I made float[3]

Comment: From what I remember of the C standard, it's implementation-defined. Arrays are *contiguously* allocated while structs are *sequentially* allocated. The difference is the compiler has permission to insert arbitrary padding into structs, while arrays are packed as tightly as alignment allows. In practice the memory layout will probably be identical, since if all struct members have the same type, it could use the same alignment as an array, and unnecessary padding would waste space. Still, the only way to know for sure is to measure it on your particular platform and compiler.

Comment: @Doval You might want to convert your comment to an answer!

Comment: @tnorgd I changed your code; I hope it's closer to what you intended; feel free to revert or clarify

Comment: @anatolyg The reason I didn't post it as an answer originally is because I don't know what loading/unloading values to/from __m128 entails. It seemed possible to me that there was some detail that might trivialize the choice between the two. Can anyone comment on that?